# High memory usage when file generated using EPPLus library

Tags: memory-leaks, epplus, red-gate-ants

[image: Profiler Sanpshot]

HI All,

Using ANTS memory profiler, I noticed that in a process of creating Excel file using EPPLUS(3.5 MB) on IIS, a lot more memory (150MB) is added to IIS Worker Process (w3wp.exe). The memory count does not go down after a download is completed. I use pretty much the same code as this one: http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c5783b32e89e#SampleApp/Sample1.cs.

EPPLus has everything I need. Except this little problem. I have also seen a few "out-of-memory" threads and none of them seems to be resolved. Please let me know if someone has faced the same issue and fixed it.

Generation 2 is holding lot of objects.

**Problem: ExcelCell Object is held in generation 2. How can i clear this without calling GC.Collect()**

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: nope. I changed to spreadsheet gear. Its a paid library. EPPPlus is great if you are working with small excel sheet and you generate files in static manner (one file at a time. if multiple users try to generate files, it creates issues)

Comment: I have the exact some problem, but i just found it out after having implemented like 20 reports using it. Im so screwed.

Comment: There is a beta of 4.0 of EPPlus which promises memory improvements, you may wish to look at that.